# Include other PSake files from dynamic location

Tags: powershell, build-automation, psake

I basically want to do this

`Invoke-psake .\deploy\deploy-resources.psake.ps1 -parameters @{"CommonScriptsPath"="C:\abc"}`

And then have the following line in my `deploy-resources.psake.ps1` file

`Include "$($CommonScriptsPath)\psake-common.ps1"`

It seems that the `Include` line is evaluated before the parameters has been assigned to the scope of the file.

How can I do this?